# VueJS DOM not updating when data does

Tags: java, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have a simple example with a button and some text but for some reason, it's not updating even though when I log the Vue object, data is clearly being updated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ showNav }}</span>
    <span class="parallax__nav__trigger" v-on:click="toggleNav">
        Menu 
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
      showNav: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      toggleNav: () => {
        this.showNav = !this.showNav
        console.log(this)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mind the `this` when declaring functions:

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
      showNav: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      toggleNav: () => {
        this.showNav = !this.showNav
        console.log(this)
      }
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
export default {
    data() {                                   // <== changed this line
      showNav: false,
    },
    methods: {
      toggleNav() {                            // <== changed this line
        this.showNav = !this.showNav
        console.log(this)
      }
    }
}
```

## Reasoning

Don't use arrow functions (`() => {}`) when declaring Vue methods. They pick up the `this` from the current scope (possibly `window`), and will not reflect the Vue instance.

From the [API Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> Note that **you should not use an arrow function with the `data` property** (e.g. `data: () => { return { a: this.myProp }}`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so `this` will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.myProp` will be undefined.